# Smoothing data with sensor error that is normally distributed

Tags: normal-distribution

I have data from a sensor that quite noisy.  I have determined the sensor's error distribution and found it to be normally distributed.

My question is:  Can this distribution be used in some way to smooth the data? Ideally some discrete function or method.

I will need to integrate it twice, and the sharp spikes get out of control the more it is integrated.  In my project, I measure acceleration and integrate to velocity and displacement.  The acc values are (as an average) close to 0.  However, the displacement turns out to be $\pm60\text{ m}$ on a stationary sensor.  I tried a first order filter that produced better results, but nowhere near $0  \text{ m}$.

EDIT:  For some reason I confused differentiation with integration...

Comment: I'm finding it hard to be sure what you're asking. You say you found it to be normally distributed. If you know the mean and the variance then you know which normal distribution it is, and the normal density is as smooth as any function ever is. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The OP says that the measurement errors are normal, but that says nothing about the distribution of the actual data itself, much in the way that simple linear regression only assumes the errors as normal, then applies OLS to fit the response to the predictors.

Comment: velocity is an antiderivative of acceleration, not a derivative. And same for displacement's relation to velocity.

Comment: Hurkyl  I updated my question.  Stupid mistake on my part.  @heropup  I was thinking that it might be possible in some way to use the known distribution to predict what the next sensor value should be.  For my case, it can be assumed that the acc should be 0.  The sensor produces noise of about $\pm0.1 \text { %} $.  Once a new sensor value is read, that value should be evaluated with historic data and the distribution to find its "true" value without the noise.  I hope that makes sense to you, Im not proficient in the jargon of this field

Comment: @22134484 : In either LaTeX or MathJax, the code \pm 1 \% yields this: $\pm 1 \%.$ You don't need \text{%} $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  Thanks.  Its been a while since I used either and forgot how to do a %.

Comment: @22134484 : I should add that in LaTeX, as opposed to MathJax, \text{%} won't work.